# gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface toolkit-accessibility true fails

Tags: gnome, docker, accessibility

My docker script executes the following two commands

```
gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface toolkit-accessibility true
gsettings get org.gnome.desktop.interface toolkit-accessibility
```

The first command runs (silently) but the second command returns false.

What sort of reasons would cause `gsettings set org.gnome.desktop.interface toolkit-accessibility` to fail? What should I be looking at?

I have installed `dbus-x11` and unsuccessfully tried to start the dbus-daemon as follows, but I'm not sure I am doing the right thing.

```
dbus-daemon --system
dbus-daemon[2702]: Failed to start message bus: Failed to bind socket "/run/dbus/system_bus_socket": No such file or directory
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution:

```
apt-get install dbus-x11
...
eval $(dbus-launch --sh-syntax)
```